# Hello, I'm trying to set up my Android Device for Flutter. Gradle Errors

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart, emulation

I'm trying to run a flutter app on my Android device. I'm receiving lots of errors. I'll post the screenshots and paste the error. Thanks in advance.

Launching lib\main.dart on SM G900H in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
>   dl.google.com
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com
>   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
>   dl.google.com
>   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 33s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Could it be an internet connection problem? Like do you have a VPN?

Comment: Not at all, I don't have one.

Answer (score 1):

hi first make sure that your region is not under restriction for that use VPN or other methods and try again and check your connection by the way then make sure that your ide can detect a proxy , if you use android studio go to settings in proxy section turn on the auto-detect proxy. I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Figured an Internet Connection was required. So the first time this runs, make sure you have an Internet connection.