# Trying to run new flutter project for android, stuck in this "can't resolve error" for days

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I created new flutter project from command prompt. I could run it for desktop and web. But can't run for android on both physical device and emulator. I am trying to find solution for two days. Still not working. i try running it both android studio and visual studio code. both latest flutter and dart plugins are installed. I am new to flutter.

I tried running another project from Github to compare. same result.
I have stable internet connection. I didn't mess anything with codes. It's newly generated.
Here's the error message.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.0/gradle-7.2.0.pom
> > Resetting to invalid mark
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10.
> > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.10.pom
> > Resetting to invalid mark

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61912919/hello-im-trying-to-set-up-my-android-device-for-flutter-gradle-errors?rq=2