# When running Flutter for Android, I got this Gradle Error

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Below is the error i got when i run it in android studio.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 912

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'.
      > No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.destinationDir() is applicable for argument types: (File) values: [C:\Users\ASUS\flutters\build\a
pp\intermediates\flutter\debug]
```

When I run my flutter app for desktop platform, it runs fine. But when I run it for Android Platform, there's an issue with Gradle. I am running it in Android Studio. I have tried Flutter clean and run. That doesn't help. I could successfully run my Kotlin and Java projects in Android Studio. I don't know what happens with Flutter.

This is part of the error message i got when i run my flutter app in visual studio. The error is too long so I can't include the whole.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on TECNO LD7 in debug mode...
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:1:1: Cannot access implicit script receiver class 'org.gradle.api.Project'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:5:1: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public open fun apply(p0: Closure<(raw) Any!>): Unit defined in Flutter_gradle
public open fun apply(p0: (Mutable)Map<String!, *>): Unit defined in Flutter_gradle
public open fun apply(p0: Action<in ObjectConfigurationAction!>): Unit defined in Flutter_gradle
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:7:26: Unresolved reference: Plugin
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:7:33: Unresolved reference: Project
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:8:5: 'apply' overrides nothing
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:8:33: Unresolved reference: Project
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:11:13: Unresolved reference: getProperty
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:12:17: Unresolved reference: getProperty
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:15:25: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline fun <reified T> ObjectFactory.setProperty(): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public inline fun <T : Any> ObjectFactory.setProperty(elementType: KClass<TypeVariable(T)>): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:16:25: Unresolved reference: getProperty
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:17:29: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline fun <reified T> ObjectFactory.setProperty(): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public inline fun <T : Any> ObjectFactory.setProperty(elementType: KClass<TypeVariable(T)>): SetProperty<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:25:25: Unresolved reference: getProperty
e: C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle.kts:26:29: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
```

This is the error I got a while ago: [Trying to run new flutter project for android, stuck in this "can't resolve error" for days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76044490/trying-to-run-new-flutter-project-for-android-stuck-in-this-cant-resolve-erro)